# rootと同じ権限を有するユーザを作成するには？

Tags: mysql

**Q1.rootと同じ権限を作成するには？**
・GRANT ALL だけではなく、「GRANT OPTION」が必要ですか？

---

**Q2.PRIVILEGESについて**
・下記の違いは何ですか？
・GRANT ALL
・GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1. `GRANT OPTION` が必要です。

Q2. `GRANT ALL` と `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` は同じです。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/grant.html

Comment: 何か特別な意味があるのだろうと思い「PRIVILEGES」付与していました……